# Что делают библиотеки -lws2_32 и -lpthread

Tags: c++

Мне  дали проект но я не могу понять

```
 # --- LIBS
 win32:LIBS += -lws2_32
 else:LIBS += -lpthread
```

для чего эти библиотеки ? И проект был написан на винде 7 (32) а у меня вида 10 (64 бит). Есть ли эти библиотеки в виндовс 10 ?
Qt b вижуал студио  одна и та же.

Comment: `win32` в кутешном `.pro` файле, это вообще всё семейство Windows, а не только 32 бит, имнип.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ws2_32 - это для ws2_32.dll, библиотека для работы с сокетами в винде. В комплекте со Студией есть. pthread - POSIX threads, в поставке винды, насколько я знаю, ее нет.